# To get label text by clicking on the sprite

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, label, sprite

I have added a sprite and added a label as the child of the sprite.
Now I want to click the sprite and get the corresponding label text .Help me with some solution.

```
bubblesprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"bubble2.png"];
bubblesprite.position=CGPointFromString([self positioning]);
[self addChild:bubblesprite];
label = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:[tempArray2 objectAtIndex:i] fontName:@"Marker Felt" fontSize:30];
label.color = ccc3(233,34,19);
[bubblesprite addChild: label z:1];
CGSize s = [bubblesprite contentSize];
label.position = ccp(s.width/2, s.height/2);
```

Comment: Please post your code for how you create the label as a child of the sprite.

Answer (score 1):

To access your labelstring use your tempArray2 `[tempArray2 objectAtIndex:i]`

I suggest to use CCMenu for your demand.

        `NSString* labelString = @"test";
        CCLabelTTF* aLabel = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:labelString fontName:@"Maker Felt" fontSize:24];
        aLabel.position = ccp(100, 100); 
        [self addChild:aLabel];
        CCMenuItemImage* button = [CCMenuItemImage itemFromNormalImage:@"Icon.png" selectedImage:@"Icon.png" target:self selector:@selector(buttonPress)];
        button.position = ccp(100, 100);
        CCMenu* menu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:button, nil];
        menu.position = ccp(0, 0);
        [self addChild:menu];`

-(void)buttonPress
{
        CCLog("%@", labelString);
}

To change the text from the label use its setText: method. This method is slow. For a fast version use CCLabelBMFont http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/0.99.5/interface_c_c_label_b_m_font.html